Particular formula for side of triangle given two sides and one angle
I have the following picture

and apparently we have this formula $$b = -c \cos(\alpha) + \sqrt{a^2-c^2\sin^2(\alpha)}.$$ I don't understand how I can show this. What I tried is to use the law of sines and the fact that the angles of the triangle sum up to $\pi$ and then use the law of cosine to get the length of $c$ but I think it is the wrong approach for the formula.

See law of cosines with supplementary angles.

You don't understand because, i guess, you don't look at the fact that sides $a$ and $c$ are data of the problem, as well as the angle $148.4^{\circ}$ formed by $c$ and the side unknown $b$.


Refer to the figure,
$BF=c\sin \alpha$
$CF=\sqrt {BC^2-CF^2}=\sqrt{a^2-c^2 \sin^2 \alpha}$
$AF=c \cos \alpha$
$\therefore b=CF-AF=\sqrt{a^2-c^2 \sin^2 \alpha}-c \cos \alpha$

Your idea of using the Law of Cosines is correct --- you're just missing one trick. To see this, since you're stuck anyway, why not work backwards:
$$\begin{split}
&\hphantom{\iff\;} b = -c \cos\alpha + \sqrt{a^2-c^2\sin^2\alpha}\\
&\iff b+ c\cos\alpha = \sqrt{a^2-c^2\sin^2\alpha} \\
&\iff b^2+2bc\cos\alpha+c^2\cos^2\alpha = a^2-c^2\sin^2\alpha\\
&\iff b^2+2bc\cos\alpha+c^2(\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha)=a^2\\
&\iff b^2 + 2bc\cos\alpha + c^2 = a^2
\end{split}$$
Which is precisely just the Law of Cosines, once you remember that the relevant angle $\angle BAC= \pi-\alpha$, and $\cos(\pi-\alpha)=-\cos\alpha$.
So the essential trick is to use the Pythagorean identity $\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha=1$. This is hard to figure out in the forwards direction, but not too tough backwards!
(Note that I've amended your original formula to add a square on the sine, as I think that's required for the formula to work.)

@jjagmath Yeah, you're right, my if and only if symbols were assuming such carefulness was taken into account. It's a bit sloppy, but I was lazy since it's "morally correct"...
